# Best way to store randomized items from RPG's?

Tags: sql, database, search, structure, items

I'd like to store a lot of items from an ARPG (Path of Exile). Problem is, I don't know any efficient way to search for them later. The game generates items with 0-10 different stats from a total pool of 100+. Each stat can have many different values (+1-10 strength for example). Some stats are clear values, while others are unique bonuses with only text.

Currently I'm trying things with a simple table like ('item_id', 'item_name', 'prefix', 'prefix_values', 'suffix', 'suffix_values') and storing multiple prefixes/suffixes as strings, which already seems kinda bad to me. For example, I'd like to search for an item with at least 28 fire resistance, 21 lightning resistance, 12 strength and 70 life.

What would be the best way to store them and how could I efficiently query them later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a few tables:

```
Items:
------
ItemID int primary key
ItemName varchar(50)

Stats:
------
StatID int primary key
StatName varchar(50)

ItemStats:
----------
ItemStatID int primary key
ItemID int foreign key (Items.ItemID)
StatID int foreign key (Stats.StatID)
Value int
```